# Why does the convergent nozzle increase the velocity of the fluid?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, fluid-dynamics

Why does the convergent nozzle increase the velocity of the fluid? According to Newton's theory, force is the reason for the increase of velocity. Does convergent nozzle cause force generation? Why does the convergent nozzle generate force? According to my understanding, the convergent nozzle will lead to an increase in the drag force of the flow, but how can this lead to an increase in velocity? Is it right that the drag force reduces the velocity?

The fluid I'm talking about here is water.

Comment: What you state is not always true. Converging nozzles imply increase in velocity for subsonic flows, decrease in velocity for supersonic flow. You can appreciate the reason studying quasi-1D compressible flows. For force balance on a control volume in the analysis, see my answer below

Comment: The fluid I'm talking about here is water.

Answer (score 2):

It's about more than just the forces.

A flow has to obey the rules of mass conservation.  If the diameter of the path changes, the velocity of the flow must also change, to maintain the same amount of mass flow at each point in the system (mass cant really just come out of nowhere or disappear to nowhere).

But as you notice, on it's own that doesnt really make sense with how the nozzle must have some drag force.  What you need to consider is how adding a nozzle changes the system.

Without a nozzle, you can find the velocity and mass flow of the fluid based on the pressure driving the flow.  If you were to introduce a converging nozzle to that flow, without changing the pressure gradient, you would get less total mass flow (although possibly with a higher velocity at the convergence). The nozzle would require more force, and therefore more pressure differential to overcome the restriction, or with the same driving force, less mass will flow per second.

[Bernoulli's Principle](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli%27s_principle) is a good way to show this, where it basically comes down to energy conservation laws.

Comment: The fluid I'm talking about here is water.Why does the convergent nozzle require more force? Is this force caused by convergent nozzle?

Answer (score 1):

I think you can figure this one out, enbin.  Here are some hints to get you started:

How is flow possible through an ordinary hose?  If the water were to start moving, a drag force would appear, opposing the motion.  What force (on a small “chunk” of water in the hose) cancels out this drag force and allows flow to proceed?

Can you apply similar analysis to your nozzle?  What forces are acting on the chunk of water inside the nozzle?

Answer (score 1):

Let's limit us to the analysis of a converging nozzle in the incompressible flow (that can be interpreted as the extreme limit of the compressible subsonic flow).

With the assumption of incompressible flow with constant density $\rho$, and steady conditions, the integral mass and momentum balance equations read

$\oint_{\partial V} \rho \mathbf{u} \cdot \mathbf{\hat{n}} = 0$  (mass)
$\oint_{\partial V} \rho \mathbf{u} \mathbf{u} \cdot \mathbf{\hat{n}} = \oint_{\partial V} \mathbf{t_n}$  (momentum)

The surface integral $\int_{\partial V} \mathbf{t_n}$ represents the total force acting on the fluid contained in the volume $V$.

Let's simplify the equations assuming uniform fields on the inner and outer sections $S_1$, $S_2$ respectively, with unit normal vectors pointing outwards the volume $V$ $\mathbf{\hat{n}}_1 = -\mathbf{\hat{x}}$, and $\mathbf{\hat{n}}_2 = \mathbf{\hat{x}}$, and assuming that the viscous stress on the inner and outer surfaces are negligible, $\mathbf{t_n}\big|_{S_{1,2}} = \underbrace{\mathbf{s_n}}_{=\mathbf{0}} - p \mathbf{\hat{n}}\big|_{S_{1,2}}$

$-\rho u_1 A_1 + \rho u_2 A_2 = 0$$\quad \text{(mass)}\quad $$\dot{m} = \rho u_1 A_1 = \rho u_2 A_2$
$\dot{m} (u_2 - u_1) = \mathbf{\hat{x}} \cdot \underbrace{\oint_{\partial V} \mathbf{t_n}}_{\mathbf{R}^{fluid}} = \mathbf{\hat{x}} \cdot \left( p_1 A_1 - p_2 A_2 + \underbrace{\oint_{S_{lat}} \mathbf{t_n}}_{\mathbf{R}^{fluid}_{fs}} \right)$$\quad \text{(momentum x-direction)} \quad$

where I introduced the total force acting on the fluid $\mathbf{R}^{fluid}$ and the contribution coming from the stress exchanged with the wall of the nozzle $\mathbf{R}^{fluid}_{fs}$. It's quite easy to verify that:

- the total force acting on the fluid points in the direction of motion of the fluid,

  $\mathbf{R}^{fluid} = \dot{m}(u_2 - u_1) = \dot{m} u_1 \underbrace{\left( 1 - \dfrac{A_2}{A_1} \right)}_{ \gt 0} \mathbf{\hat{x}}$
- the force acting on the walls of the nozzle reads (after some algebra)

  $\mathbf{R}^{solid}_{fs} = - \mathbf{R}^{fluid}_{fs} = \underbrace{\left[ P_2 ( A_1 - A_2 ) + \dfrac{1}{2} \rho ( u_1 - u_2 )^2 \right]}_{ \gt 0} \mathbf{\hat{x}}$

  with the assumption that the boundary layer is thin so that the core of the flow is irrotational, so that the Bernoulli equation holds $P + \frac{1}{2} \rho |\mathbf{u}|^2$. So the force acting on the wall of the nozzle pushes the nozzle in the direction of the flow, while the flow experience a deceleration from it.

To cut a long story short, the influence of the pressure decrease in the nozzle pushing the flow in the direction of motion is larger than the influence of the wall reaction that makes the flow velocity decrease.

Comment: The fluid I'm talking about here is water.

Comment: Is the convergent nozzle obstructing or not obstructing the flow of fluid?

Comment: If the fluid is water, what I've done is ok, since we can consider it as a incompressible fluid with constant density (as I did in my answer). The nozzle, as far as it works as a nozzle (let's say "small" angle even if there is no problem of flow separation in convergent regions, usually), is not obstructing the fluid. Moreover, the wall is "sucked" toward the inner part, if we assume that the inflow pressure is equal to the atmospheric pressure acting on the other side of the wall

Comment: the wall is "sucked" toward the inner part？

Comment: if $P_1$ equals the atmospheric pressure acting on the upper side of the wall, the wall feels a force the push it towards the fluid. This is because on the upper side pressure equal Patm, while on the lower side pressure is lower, since it starts as Patm and decreases as section of the nozzle decreases and the velocity increases

Comment: You should have a diagram. I don't understand what you mean.